# Bandwidth Optimization options locked

Tags: 8, performance, configuration

I'm running a largely default Drupal 8.0.0-RC2 site. At `/admin/config/development/performance` the **"Bandwidth Optimization"** settings for "Aggregate CSS Files" and "Aggregate Javascript files" are disabled, so I cannot change their state. Extensive though fruitless googling suggests this is unusual, but I'm stumped on where to start. I'm using the [Drude environment](https://github.com/blinkreaction/drude) for my site.

[image]

Comment: what version of Drupal 8 are you using?

Comment: Drupal version 8.0.0-rc2

Comment: humm might be a bug, have you tried doing it on a clean install without installing any extra modules?

Comment: Only core is currently enabled. Switched to the ironically-named "Seven" theme, checkboxes remain disabled.

Comment: Disable JS and try again. I currently have issues #states going wild in RC2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem with the public directory, it is not configured or it is not writable. You can check this with drush:

```
drush ev "var_dump(is_dir('public://'), is_writable('public://'))"
```

Result should be:

```
    bool(true)
    bool(true)
```

If these two conditions are true, then the checkboxes will be available.

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem, thank you. I did see a UI notice about the "Public" directory needing to be configured, which it was, but I missed any notice about writable. That eval script is most helpful. Obviously, "Files" should be writable. Running drude turns some basic LAMP stack management practices around.